How different is Wittgenstein's Language game from Contextuality?
Contextuality
Language game
Per Wittgenstein:

Words are missing essence
Meaning is use

The way I understood it, a word's meaning is decided by the language game it is part of.
This is either identical to or is too similar to contextuality where word meanings are determined by context e.g. the word "table" means a piece of furniture in "this table is made of wood" and a particular arrangement of data in "use the table to plot a graph"
If language games is identical to contextuality then Wittgenstein hasn't said anything new; we always knew words vary in meaning with context.
If language games is only similar to contextuality, there's got to be a subtle difference between the two. I however am unable to put a finger on what the "subtle difference" is.
Question: Is Wittgenstein's language merely a restatement of an already well-known fact, contextuality?

Did Wittgenstein who influenced John McDowell to understand philosophy as therapeutic ever self-claimed he did find something new and ground breaking in his publications?...

Frege's contextuality only suggests that 'meanings' may shift, it still admits a 'core' literal meaning or essence that gets modified by contextual 'accidents' or connotations. And Frege's "context" is a proposition, which is the carrier of full 'meaning'. Wittgenstein's suggestion was much more radical, no essence, not for words and not for propositions, only linguistic role in the sum total of uses. It is the difference between essentialism and non-essentialism, local and global holism.

@DoubleKnot, it's just that when peeps dicuss Wittgenstein they seem to do so as if it's not the same as contextuality (as if it were a different concept).

@Conifold, so contextuality doesn't deny essentialism while language games do. My next question is Wittgenstein is (only) denying an essence to words across "contexts" and not within a context, right? For example in Christian discourse the word "God" does have an essence, but in interreligious discourse, the participants may be referring to different things by "God".

Essence, as understood since Aristotle, is the invariant across change, it is hard to talk of it when the context is not varied. And "God", even in Christian language games, is interpreted by family resemblance, as Wittgenstein would put it, rather than by essence. Linguistic role is an extrinsic ex post facto notion that bundles extant uses, not a mental or ideal entity that precedes and underlies those uses, as 'meaning' or 'sense' was supposed to be (compare to Hume's bundle theory of the self). No "things" are there to refer to.

The principle of contextuality is the claim that a word only has a (determinate) meaning in the context of a sentence (in particular: a proposition). This claim can be traced back to Frege and others in the 19th century. (See for instance:
Compositionality: its historic context, T.M.V. Janssen, 2012
Wilhelm Wundt, the neurophysiologist and empirical psychologist (quoted by Janssen) formulated it as:

The real thinking consists of thoughts, and separated from a thought in which it enters a concept has no existence. The same holds for an isolated word in ordinary language when used as a sign for a concept; it has reality only in the context of a sentence. (Wundt, Logik. Eine Untersuchung der Principien der Erkenntnis und der Methoden wissenschafliche Forschung, 1883)

A related, but different, and apparently contradictory claim is the principle of compositionality which is the claim that the meaning of a sentence is composed of the meanings of the individual words. Frege seems to have been dead-set against that because it can threaten "psychologism" (the reduction of mathematics to psychological operations or mere mental "concepts") which seems to make the objectivity and certainty of mathematics inexplicable.
Wittgenstein was strongly influenced by Frege, especially in his early work , but some influence persisted in his later work. The slogan "meaning is use" is a somewhat crude, popularized summary of Wittgenstein's core ideas in the Philosophical Investigations. In Philosophical Investigation 43 he wrote

For a large class of cases of the employment of the word ‘meaning’ —though not for all — this word can be explained in this way: the meaning of a word is its use in the language.

In the Philosophical Investigations this idea is closely connected with his "language games"; it's mainly developed in the context of a pretty far-reaching critique of essentialist (platonist, realist) and psychologist ideas about how words (especially names) and phrases acquire meaning. The critique also implies a thorough repudation of some of his own earlier ideas. For instance in PI 46 he writes:

What lies behind the idea that names really signify simples? (goes on to quote Plato, a quote that ends with) "... For the essence of speech is the composition of names." Both Russell's 'individuals' and my 'objects' (Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus) were such primary elements.

The term "language game" is primarily used in the PI to refer to certain artificial toy "languages" - languages that are much simpler than full-blown everyday language, and that thereby may make it easier to get a handle on the question how meaning is acquired or how meaning can change. Witgenstein uses these "languages games" as a conceptual tool, as thought experiments, to investigate those tricky questions.
The suggestion then is to use game playing as metaphor of how language is generally used (how meaning can be acquired/established/changed/explained/justified).
In the form of a statement you could summarize this as: "Words (or phrases or sentences) acquire meaning by their embedding in social game-like activities."
The way I interpret this is that this is a broader, more general, and vaguer claim than contextualism. The 'ultimate' context for language, you might say, is "forms of life", in other words, certain social customs, behavioral patterns -- but that is an extension of the idea of contextuality. Wittgenstein's "language game" idea can be seen as compatible with both the narrow principle of contextuality and the principle of compositionality.
Wittgenstein's ideas about "meaning as use" and language as family of language games get a more precise, operational, empirical content in computational linguistics. The basic hypothesis (basic for the development of word-embeddings and LLMs) is the distributional hypothesis:

Linguistic items (of whatever kind) with similar (syntagmatic or paradigmatic) probability distributions, have a similar (syntactical) role or (semantic) meaning.

As we've seen, the resulting models have certain peculiar weaknesses, but they are also extremely powerful. The dialogue systems that are built on top of them essentially also parse and generate language in a game-like environment (for instance, there is very strict turn-taking; the human asks a question; the system generates a response). And the rules of the game are - as in Wittgenstein's toy language games - never completely fixed or determined (apart from deep rules that are not accessible to the surface system).
"Meaning" in these systems is in principle totally undetermined. That is,
at any given moment, in actual use, relative to a particular system, relative to particular tasks, it may be determined. But a single word or phrase (or a sequence of letters) can not meaningfully be assigned a "meaning" outside of the system and the tasks that the system is trained on or expected to satisfy. So, like (or even more than) Wittgenstein's language games (and like William James' ideas of language) the implied philosophy of meaning is thoroughly pragmatic. "Context" -- again similar to considering a language game as "context" -- also has a much wider meaning than in the 19th century discussions (it's the context of a large corpus of utterances; both the horizontal/temporal/sequential context and the paradigmatic context; plus the context of different tasks, different modes of deployment, the goals of the community that encounters/uses/produces the system).

+1 Outstanding. For the OP, you might be interested in technical literature related to the notion that meaning doesn't inhabit the word, but the context around it, particularly in the application of LLM technology. See https://transformer-circuits.pub/2024/scaling-monosemanticity/index.html.

Ok, will need to reread that. Meanwhile a question. Is Wittgenstein saying words lack a fixed essence or that words lack any essence whatever? These are different claims and if the latter, communication is impossible. Within a particular language game, words do possess an essence,

Then Wittgenstein is generalizing the meaning of context to include nonlinguistic elements that are better covered by the phrase form of life, oui? I say this because if language games are only for language, that's ground already covered by contextuality. I wish we had a good example for what Wittgenstein meant.

@Hudjefa - As I see it, language games are practices (limited, game like) that embed forms of language. W gives several concrete examples. So, it's indeed correct to say that this "context" is broader than just linguistic context: it's the whole pragmatic context (including other actions, perceptions, thought, social customs). But the idea of contextuality can be seen as a core idea: meaning is established (or fails to be established) relative to the whole pragmatic context.

So, Ws originality (in the PI) is not really in his general ideas - lots of them were in some form or other already proposed in some form - but in his methods: careful examination of particular "toy" language games ("toy" doesn't mean not real - they use the whole apparatus of language) by persistent questions. Those questions are meant to undermine certain false ideas about what "meaning" is (essentialist, realist ones). It's not the case that W had no beliefs about which philosophical "theories" were wrong. It's just so, that he only suggested approaches to find true theories.

Btw - The "interpretation game" as played by the academic philosophical community I find mostly totally baffling and irrelevant (e.g. Kripke interpreting W and then others commenting on the commenting and coming up with yet other interpretations, etc etc ad nauseam.) The useful and creative follow-up ideas about language and "how thought works" or what creativity is almost all seem to have come from computational (and cognitive) scientists.

Mudskipper's answer is excellent, and I'll respond in a briefer fashion, to point you in a direction of work that might be of interest to you.
Wittgenstein's notion of the Sprachspiel cuts against his earlier philosophical work in Tractatus and his thinking defending what some call logical atomism. From WP:

Its principal exponent was the British philosopher Bertrand Russell. It is also widely held that the early works[a] of his Austrian-born pupil and colleague, Ludwig Wittgenstein, defend a version of logical atomism, though he went on to reject it in his later Philosophical Investigations.

For a more technical and deeper analysis than the WP article, see both the SEP's Russell's Logical Atomism and Wittgenstein's Logical Atomism.
The point of logical atomism, as best as I understand it, is to embrace the Principle of Compositionality and reduce propositions, the abstract notion of meaning bearers which form complete thoughts to analysis of relations expressed through syntax which bottomed out in terms. From there, if one can claim that the terms, most of which represent categories (SEP), can be grasped, then the combination of the terms and the logical structure which governed their relationship provided a complete meaning of the sentence. Propositional calculus in this way makes way for the more useful predicate calculus that Frege was instrumental in putting forth.
By the time of Philosophical Investigations, it became clear to LW that there was more involved in communication, and that in some regard not just the linguistic context, but the context of usage from the perspective of agent was involved in determining meaning. LW was therefore recognizing what modern linguistics call pragmatics. From the SEP:

The words ‘yes,’ ‘perhaps,’ and ‘no’ each has a perfectly identifiable meaning, known by every speaker of English (including not very competent ones). However, as those lines illustrate, it is possible for different speakers in different circumstances to mean different things using those words.

So, under this view of language, it's not enough to know the atomics of the proposition. Words themselves have meanings, not explicitly carried by the sign, but implicitly assigned by those who utter and interpret. Here, the order is inverted. The syntax doesn't function to compose the terms into units of meaning, rather, the word as meaning bearer now gets assigned by its role in the proposition. Or the wider passage of text, or as LW recognized: the meaning of words can actually be determined by the intention of the utterer.
Thus, what LW was drawing attention to was the intention of the speaker as providing knowledge about the language itself. The meaning of the words have to be inferred by the hearer by assessing the intent of the speaker. That's a far cry from earlier theories of language that build up meaning of proposition from terms and relationships. It fundamentally requires that one looks at the utterance and assesses what relevance the utterance has to the utterer.
In modern pragmatic analysis, informed by cognitive science, this thesis of LW's is taken to an extreme by the works of Dan Sperber and Deirdre Wilson who put forth relevance theory. From WP:

The theory takes its name from the principle that "every utterance conveys the information that it is relevant enough for it to be worth the addressee's effort to process it", that is, if I say something to you, you can safely assume that I believe that the conveyed information is worthwhile your effort to listen to and comprehend it; and also that it is "the most relevant one compatible with the communicator's abilities and preferences", that is, I tried to make the utterance as easy to understand as possible, given its information content and my communicative skills.

Thus, Wittgenstein with his notion of Sprachspiel set in motion the development of pragmatics and with it, changes in philosophy of language put developed further by Grice, Austin, Strawson, and others. This can be understood as the movement of understanding semantics to be conveyed by words from the externalism of meaning advocated by Frege, who was fervently an anti-psychologist to an internalized notion of meaning which is highly contextualized (no big surprise to a student of Japanese), a position supported by modern scientific realism.

Thanks for providing extra pointers and references.

I will need some time to process your answer. Ad interim, I can't see how any form of discourse is possible sans an essence to words. If you read my comment to mudskipper's answer, you'll get a better idea of what I'm confused about.

So when Wittgenstein announced that many philosophical problems are pseudoproblems he was drawing the distinction you mention in your post.

@Hudjefa - You have to make it more concrete and try to think it through. The problems or questions are not 'pseudoproblems'; it's specific philosophical "theories" , including "folk-philosophical" views, about what meaning is or how it is acquired that do not really explain what they purport to explain and that seem to be produced by the confusing "grammar" of (Indo-European) language(s). It's perfectly valid to talk about the meaning of a word - in ordinary or scientific contexts. But this talk can becomes "weird" in philosophical contexts (W uses that word I believe).

The 'pseudoproblems' position is imo more the one that W had in the Tractatus - which was based on an oversimplified view of factual knowledge and a reductive, absolutist view of logic and language. The core idea of the Tract - the saying/showing distinction - is important, though - it's basically the same, I think, as the idea of contextuality (but in the wide, pragmatic sense). You might say (letting these concepts slip a little out of focus): the context is always what 'shows itself' and cannot be 'said'.

So, you say, I cannot see how any communication is possible "sans an essence to words". But what do you mean by that whole phrase? (In LLMs we don't even need a concept of "word" anymore. And if we do use it, a word's "meaning" (as word embedding) is a high-dimensional vector of reals encoding its possible uses and relations to other "words". So, at any given moment, in actual use, yes, there has to be some underlying parameters for either "words" or word-fragments, that allow the system to "grasp" meaning.)

@Hudjefa According to relevance theory, an essence to words would be for two parties to rely on codes to conduct inferences about intentions in communications, so far as communication involves words, indeed, words and their conventional assignment of meaning play a role, but what is to be grasped is that those "essences" are arbitrary as conventions, and therefore subsumed in terms of communication by playing a role in the act of inference. The same is true for the arbitrariness of syntax. That's why when you hear a foreign language unfamiliar with you, you cannot identify "essences" at all...

You cannot recognize the phonemes, the morphemes and lexemes, and therefore the semantics they carry, because the sounds in the medium that you tranduce don't carry the meaning, the meaning is assigned as a judgement through the act of interpretation which is heavily guided by textual context and intention of the sender. Semantics arrives not from words, which are somewhat arbitrary units of meaning that are efficient for psycholinguistic reason, but from the interpretation of those words within a pragmatic framework.

@Hudjefa - A passage in which Wittgenstein tackles your question head-on is Philosophical Investigations 57. (For a somewhat wider context you could start reading at PI 43 or 46).

Also the very important PI 65. (It's best, when you start reading W. to not read any commentators or summaries or the SEP -- since they invariably seem to muddle up what he is doing -- but read him directly. Sola scriptura as the protestants say :) )

@mudskipper, Wittgenstein is positing an alternative to meaning as essence, which is meaning as use. For him use is the antithesis of essence (they're mutually exclusive); if not there's no grist for the mill.

@Hudjefa - Yes, that's what I'm saying.

That is, his position is not an alternative, it's a correction. "meaning as essence" is misguided and wrong according to W. To find out what words like "meaning", "understanding", "rule", "game" actually mean, look at how they are actually used, don't invent some "theory" that doesn't even come close to explaining their full meanings (which are always multiple).

@mudskipper, that's interesting to know. How does all that you've said augment/supplement your and JD's original answers to the question. You said Wittgenstein's contextuality + and JD brought up what could possibly be summed up as subjectivity in discourse.

@Hudjefa - I don't really know how it augments it - I mean for me this is all the same package as it were. My comments just try to further clarify the answers. (I know JD pointed at some extra links - so, my comment is a bit in opposition to that - but of course I don't have any principled objections to using secundary sources - It's just that I think that to start with it's better to first read W yourself. Since it's not that hard to follow him if you just do a slow, close reading.)

@mudskipper, good advice. I shall read Wittgenstein.

@Hudjefa I think relevant PI53 and 54 are important. PI53 "It can be said that what we call a rule of a language-game may have very different roles in the game". PI54 "One learns the game by watching how others play it."

@JD do you have a download link to PI by any chance?

@Hudjefa I do not sorry. I have Wiley-Blackwell's version. Comes with the original German.
